# Writing continuous stats of sorted data in R

Tags: r, statistics

new to R so apologies if the question is dumb. I have a dataset of historical ordered data, lets say games in a league and players making or missing shots.

| GAME_ID | EVENT_ID | EVENT_TYPE | PLAYER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | MADE_SHOT | 25 |
| 1 | 2 | MADE_SHOT | 22 |
| 1 | 3 | MISSED_SHOT | 25 |
| 1 | 4 | MADE_SHOT | 22 |
| 2 | 1 | MADE_SHOT | 25 |
| 2 | 2 | MADE_SHOT | 22 |
| 3 | 1 | MISSED_SHOT | 25 |
| 3 | 2 | MADE_SHOT | 22 |

so i am looking at two players (Mr. 22 and 25), three games, and several shot attempts with different outcome.

What i am trying to get as a result is this:

| GAME_ID | EVENT_ID | EVENT_TYPE | PLAYER_ID | SHOTS_ATTEMPTED | SHOTS_MADE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | MADE_SHOT | 25 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | MADE_SHOT | 22 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | MISSED_SHOT | 25 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | MADE_SHOT | 22 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | MADE_SHOT | 25 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | MADE_SHOT | 22 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | MISSED_SHOT | 25 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | MADE_SHOT | 22 | 4 | 4 |

I need to be able to step through the table and find each players' stats for the moment he attempted a shot.

Thought of stepping through the rows, keeping track of the last record for each player in an auxiliary dataset but i find that quite clumsy and even then i struggle to find the right functions to match and write / update. Is there an easy elegant way for this in R?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use the tidyverse ecosystem?

Comment: I did include it in my script (without really knowing why). Is there a function i could use?

Comment: I misunderstood your question initially, `cumsum` would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum` for this

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(PLAYER_ID) %>%
  mutate(
    SHOTS_ATTEMPTED = cumsum(EVENT_TYPE == "MADE_SHOT" | EVENT_TYPE == "MISSED_SHOT"),
    SHOTS_MADE = cumsum(EVENT_TYPE == "MADE_SHOT")
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Which will give

```
# A tibble: 8 × 6
# Groups:   PLAYER_ID [2]
  GAME_ID EVENT_ID EVENT_TYPE  PLAYER_ID SHOTS_ATTEMPTED SHOTS_MADE
    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>           <int>      <int>
1       1        1 MADE_SHOT          25               1          1
2       1        2 MADE_SHOT          22               1          1
3       1        3 MISSED_SHOT        25               2          1
4       1        4 MADE_SHOT          22               2          2
5       2        1 MADE_SHOT          25               3          2
6       2        2 MADE_SHOT          22               3          3
7       3        1 MISSED_SHOT        25               4          2
8       3        2 MADE_SHOT          22               4          4
```

Comment: This produced exactly the desired result! However, the subsequent processing is significantly slowed down - i can reproduce it by commenting the new lines out. Are those values for SHOTS_ATTEMPTED and SHOTS_MADE not static after the mutate, but dynamically calculated when i step through the dataset? Again pardon the probably ignorant question

Comment: You might need to add an `%>% ungroup()` at the end so that subsequent steps aren't working unnecessarily on grouped data.

Comment: You can also use `data %>% mutate(SHOTS_ATTEMPTED = cumsum(EVENT_TYPE == "MADE_SHOT" | EVENT_TYPE == "MISSED_SHOT"), SHOTS_MADE = cumsum(EVENT_TYPE == "MADE_SHOT"), .by = PLAYER_ID)` so that the grouping is explicitly just for that step.

Comment: Jon is correct. You can `ungroup` the data as this is a single operation. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This solved my problem beautifully even though i dont understand really (i didnt know the "group by" generally acts like a view). Thank you everyone.

Comment: @JonSpring can i ask a similar question? If i watned to have a number of games a player played in a different column what would i do? I tried to figure it out with cumsum but its not the correct tool. The idea of basically to group by player and game id, write 1 for every action of first game, 2 for second game and so on. Any idea?

Comment: `GAMES_PLAYED = n_distinct(GAME_ID)` within the same mutate, either with `group_by(PLAYER_ID) %>%` and `ungroup()` on either side, or `.by = PLAYER_ID` inside the mutate.

Comment: @JonSpring apologies i got no notification about your solution so i opened a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77125288/writing-continuous-stats-of-sorted-data-in-r-part-2

I tried this, however the result is the number of games played in the entire dataset, not at this particular point in time.

Comment: Gotcha. I misunderstood what you meant by "number of games a player played" so the other answer is more responsive.