# Writing continuous stats of sorted data in R - part 2

Tags: r

I have a dataset of games in chronological order, containing an entry for every action every player takes in every game. I need a field that denotes the game count for the individual player at the given moment. I already asked a question regarding a similar field here: [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77018227/writing-continuous-stats-of-sorted-data-in-r). The solution was to use grouping and cumsum, however i cant get it to work for this situation.

The data looks like this:

| GAME_ID | EVENT_ID | EVENT_TYPE | PLAYER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | MADE_SHOT | 25 |
| 1 | 2 | MADE_SHOT | 22 |
| 1 | 3 | MISSED_SHOT | 25 |
| 1 | 4 | MADE_SHOT | 22 |
| 2 | 1 | MADE_SHOT | 25 |
| 2 | 2 | MADE_SHOT | 22 |
| 2 | 3 | MADE_SHOT | 30 |
| 3 | 1 | MISSED_SHOT | 25 |
| 3 | 2 | MADE_SHOT | 22 |
| 3 | 3 | MISSED_SHOT | 30 |

what i need is this additional attribute:

| GAME_ID | EVENT_ID | EVENT_TYPE | PLAYER_ID | Games_Played |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | MADE_SHOT | 25 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | MADE_SHOT | 22 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | MISSED_SHOT | 25 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | MADE_SHOT | 22 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | MADE_SHOT | 25 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | MADE_SHOT | 22 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | MADE_SHOT | 30 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | MISSED_SHOT | 25 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | MADE_SHOT | 22 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | MISSED_SHOT | 30 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it working using a similar approach as before. We can again group by `PLAYER_ID` and then count the occurences of these IDs in each match. See below an updated version of the previous code.

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(PLAYER_ID) %>%
  mutate(
    SHOTS_ATTEMPTED = cumsum(EVENT_TYPE == "MADE_SHOT" | EVENT_TYPE == "MISSED_SHOT"),
    SHOTS_MADE = cumsum(EVENT_TYPE == "MADE_SHOT"),
    GAMES_PLAYED = cumsum(!duplicated(GAME_ID))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 7
   GAME_ID EVENT_ID EVENT_TYPE  PLAYER_ID SHOTS_ATTEMPTED SHOTS_MADE GAMES_PLAYED
     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>           <int>      <int>        <int>
 1       1        1 MADE_SHOT          25               1          1            1
 2       1        2 MADE_SHOT          22               1          1            1
 3       1        3 MISSED_SHOT        25               2          1            1
 4       1        4 MADE_SHOT          22               2          2            1
 5       2        1 MADE_SHOT          25               3          2            2
 6       2        2 MADE_SHOT          22               3          3            2
 7       2        3 MADE_SHOT          30               1          1            1
 8       3        1 MISSED_SHOT        25               4          2            3
 9       3        2 MADE_SHOT          22               4          4            3
10       3        3 MISSED_SHOT        30               2          1            2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ave

```
> ave(df$GAME_ID,list(df$EVENT_ID,df$PLAYER_ID),FUN=seq)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 3 3 2
```